# "undefined reference to `vkCreateInstance@12'" error when compiling C++ using Vulkan

Tags: c++, mingw, vulkan

I am trying to learn C++ and Vulkan while using windows 10. I have created a small program that I am compling with minGW. However when I add `vkCreateInstance(&instanceinfo, nullptr, &myvulkaninstance)` i get an error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDoOvlg.o:Renderer.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to 'vkCreateInstance@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I get the above error in the 'Renderer.cpp' in the 'InitializeInstance' method (code can be seen below).

To compile my project I use this line in CMD `g++ -L "C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.154.1/Lib/vulkan-1.lib" main.cpp Renderer.h Renderer.cpp -o build.exe`. I do not know if I am compiling the library for Vulkan correctly as I was unable to find any good documentation about that online.

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Renderer.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Renderer renderer;

    return 0;
}
```

> Renderer.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Renderer.h"

// I again don't know if this is the right way to include this header
#include "C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.154.1/Include/vulkan/vulkan.h"

using namespace std;

Renderer::Renderer(){

}

void Renderer::InitializeInstance(){
    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo {};
    instanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;

     // This is the line where i get the error
     auto error = vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, nullptr, &vulkanInstance); // <--

     if(VK_SUCCESS != error){
        std::exit(-1);
     }
}

Renderer::~Renderer(){

}
```

I have been using OpenGL and java (using LWJGL) for a while but now I wanted to learn Vulkan and C++. I am however still learning so I don't know a lot about any of these subjects. If you know how I could improve my compiling and/or prevent this error, please let me know.

Comment: The problem seems to be how you are linking the vulkan library.

Comment: `-L` is the library folder not the library. `-l` is the library file.

Comment: When I change the `-L` to `-l` it gives me this error: `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/VulkanSDK/1.2.154.1/Lib/vulkan-1.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: I am not sure (because I don't use gcc often) but you may need a space between `-l` and  `C:`

Comment: When I tried this I already had a space there however in the error log it shows the error without the space.

Comment: I think you can leave out the `-l`.  The compiler driver is smart enough to infer the fact that it's a library from the file extension.

Comment: Yes, indeed. This solves that problem but then I am back to my other error (as explained in the thread above): `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7LZbGu.o:Renderer.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to 'vkCreateInstance@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: I think you need to put the .lib after the .cpp files.

Comment: I did that, however that did not change my outcome.